# MFMessageComposeViewController first alloc takes seconds

Tags: objective-c, ios, alloc

I am trying to show an MFMessageComposeViewController with the following code:

```
controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", itemString, amountString, callTimeString];   
    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"12345678"];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is when I press the button to bring up the MFMessageComposeViewController, the alloc takes a few seconds. I have tried moving the alloc line to my viewDidLoad method, however this just moves the problem and I end up waiting a few seconds for the view to load.

Is there any method to speed up the alloc and showing of my MFMessageComposeViewController or use a delegate method or something?

Thanks.

Comment: this is for sms, have u jailbroken your device?

Comment: This is for sms on an unjailbroken, ios5, iphone4S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you are doing seems about right. You are not doing anything wrong. Check this - [Can't set recipients of MFMessageComposeViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575784/cant-set-recipients-of-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller) & the link attached in the answer

Comment: That's what I thought. Even using the exact code from that tutorial, I get a delay when first allocing the MFMessageComposeViewController of up to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, check out my answer here: [I need a callback when MFMessegeComposeViewController finally loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256141/i-need-a-callback-when-mfmessegecomposeviewcontroller-finally-loads/15257109#15257109)

For me it wasn't the alloc taking too long, it was the `presentModalViewController` of the `MFMessageComposeViewController`, which blocks on Apple's code on the UI thread, so no way to background it except for throwing up your own progress view.