# I need a callback when MFMessegeComposeViewController finally loads

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a MFMessageComposeViewController in my app, and sometimes the recipient count can get up to 200 or so. When testing on a 4S, it takes up to 10 seconds (!!) to load the sms view after I click my button. I imagine it could be even longer with older devices.

This is obviously too long for a blocking call without a loading view, but I can't put a loading view up if I have no callback when the view actually loads! There's only 1 callback in the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol, but that only calls back after the sms view is dismissed, not when it loads. Any ideas?

I'm thinking maybe grabbing callbacks from somewhere else in the modal view loading logic, or last resort I could just put a 5-10 second loading screen and hope it's up by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I found out that I was using an older version of [UIViewController's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW75) `presentViewController:animated:completion:` so I didn't have the "completion" part implemented. This is definitely the best option for my purposes to just dismiss my loading view in the completion block, but it does only work on iOS 5.0 and up. If you have to support lower than 5.0 maybe Edwin's answer would help.

**UPDATE**: Using my above method actually didn't work in practice. If I threw up a progress view and then called `presentViewController:animated:completion:` on the `MFMessageComposeViewController`, it would still make the blocking call before the progress view even showed up. I'm assuming it was something to do with the run loop not completing before the blocking call started so no UI changes would come up.

Instead I just had my progress view make a callback when it actually showed up, and then in the callback I would start loading up the `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Then, when the `MFMessageComposeViewController` callback was fired I would dismiss my progress view as well as the `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Success!

Answer (score 2):

[MFMessageComposeViewController is a subclass of UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Have you tried implementing any of UINavigationControllerDelegate's methods. Specifically:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```